# What Biblical prophecies appear to have been fulfilled already?

Tags: tanach, prophecies

Which explicit prophecies written in the torah and in the books of the prophets (Tanach) appear to have been fulfilled already?

I am asking regarding prophecies about future times from when the book was written. Not prophecies while or before the book was put into writing.

please give details of each prophecy (the verses) and how it appears to have been fulfilled.

For example, regarding the exile: "And the Lord will scatter you among all the nations, from one end of the earth to the other" (Deut.28:64), appears to have been fulfilled.

Comment: The prophesy of the seventy years of exile was fulfilled, the prophesy of Koresh letting the Jews return to Israel was fulfilled.

Comment: @sabbahillel when was this prophecy put to writing?

Comment: [Isaiah 44:28](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15975#v=28) was written before the destruction of the first temple. Isaiah lived toward the end of the reign of King Uzziah and throughout the reigns of King Jotham, Ahaz and Hezekiah and was killed by his grandson king Menashe

Comment: While not a prophecy, a number of sages have stated that every "curse" mentioned in parshat Ki Tavo has been palce on Jews at some point in our history.

Comment: ray Note if you plan on using @sabbahillel's info as an argument to others, most biblical scholars believe that that section was written by someone else well after Isaiah died (see too [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76717/759)). So you'd only be convincing to someone who already believes it.

Comment: @sabbahillel yes. but who put together the book of Isaiah?

Comment: According to Bava Basrah 14b King Chizkiya and his bais din wrote (edited) Yeshayah (from the prophecies given and passed down by Yeshaya) Thus it had already been written in its final form before the destruction of the first temple.

Comment: usfor hakochavim - ko yiheye zaracha.

Comment: @LN6595 aren't jews are among the smallest of all nations

Comment: @ray It's a frequently misunderstood prophecy. If you look closely, it simply means the Jews will be uncountable. Jews form a population which can never be properly tallied (censuses are merely estimates.)

Answer (score 1):

There are three noteworthy prophecies of Ezekiel regarding Tyre that were fulfilled much after the book of Ezekiel was written and completed. The first one is regarding the demise of Tyre,

> וּנְתַתִּיךְ לִצְחִיחַ סֶלַע מִשְׁטַח חֲרָמִים תִּהְיֶה לֹא תִבָּנֶה
>   עוֹד כִּי אֲנִי יְדֹוָד דִּבַּרְתִּי נְאֻם אֲדֹנָי
>    יֱדֹוִד:

This verse contains two predictions: 1) that Tyre will be destroyed and never regain its previous stature. 2) that the island will become a spot for the fisherman to spread their nets (משטח חרמים). The first one indeed occurred in the times of Alexander the great. For six months he besieged it till he broke through their defenses and reduced it to ruins, and since then it was never rebuilt. The second one has also undoubtedly been fulfilled,

> Historian Philip Myers said, “Alexander the Great reduced it [Tyre] to
>   ruins (332 B.C.). She recovered in a measure from this blow, but never
>   regained the place she had previously held in the world. The larger
>   part of the site … is now as bare as the top of a rock–a place where
>   the fishermen that still frequent the spot spread their nets to dry”
>   (General History for Colleges and High Schools [Boston: Ginn and Co.,
>   1889], p. 55). That fulfills the prophecies of Ezekiel 26:4-5, 14. The
>   island city was repopulated, later to be destroyed by the Moslems in
>   A.D. 1281. However, God said the mainland city would never be
>   rebuilt–and it never has. Jerusalem has been rebuilt many times but
>   Tyre will never be rebuilt because a prophet in Babylon said
>   twenty-five centuries ago, “Thou shalt be built no more” (Ezek.
>   26:14).

There is one more remarkable prophecy regarding Tyre that its accuracy astounds the reader,

> כִּי כֹה אָמַר אֲדֹנָי יֱדֹוִד בְּתִתִּי אֹתָךְ עִיר
>   נֶחֱרֶבֶת כֶּעָרִים אֲשֶׁר לֹא נוֹשָׁבוּ בְּהַעֲלוֹת עָלַיִךְ אֶת
>   תְּהוֹם וְכִסּוּךְ הַמַּיִם הָרַבִּים: (כ) וְהוֹרַדְתִּיךְ אֶת
>   יוֹרְדֵי בוֹר אֶל עַם עוֹלָם וְהוֹשַׁבְתִּיךְ בְּאֶרֶץ תַּחְתִּיּוֹת
>   כָּחֳרָבוֹת מֵעוֹלָם אֶת יוֹרְדֵי בוֹר לְמַעַן לֹא תֵשֵׁבִי וְנָתַתִּי
>   צְבִי בְּאֶרֶץ חַיִּים:

Indeed this has been fulfilled,

> In his memoirs, a section is included concerning the city of Tyre.
>   From Sidon it is half a day’s journey to Sarepta (Sarfend), which
>   belongs to Sidon. Thence it is a half-day to New Tyre (Sur), which is
>   a very fine city, with a harbour in its midst.... There is no harbour
>   like this in the whole world. Tyre is a beautiful city.... In the
>   vicinity is found sugar of a high class, for men plant it here, and
>   people come from all lands to buy it. A man can ascend the walls of
>   New Tyre and see ancient Tyre, which the sea has now covered, lying at
>   a stone’s throw from the new city. And should one care to go forth by
>   boat, one can see the castles, market-places, streets, and palaces in
>   the bed of the sea (1907, emp. added.).
>
> From this twelfth-century A.D. text, then, we learn that by that
>   period of time the city known as ancient Tyre lay completely buried
>   beneath the sea and a new city, most likely on some part of the
>   island, had been erected.
>
> In addition, Benjamin Tudela’s quote corresponds precisely to the
>   statement that the prophet made in the latter part of chapter 26: “For
>   thus says the Lord God: ‘When I make you a desolate city, like the
>   cities that are not inhabited, when I bring the deep upon you, and
>   great waters cover you’” (26:19, emp. added).

These prophecies have been so amazingly accurately fulfilled, that it caused some scholars to doubt the date of its composition (the book of Ezekiel). But  in reality it couldn't have been composed or even edited later than the second century BC (the time most of the Septuagint was written), and since the destruction of Tyre happened in the year 332 BC, there is not much room left for parts to have been inserted by editors. There is more evidence that the book has not been tampered with (since the prophecies of Ezekiel were written down during the exile), since the seemingly unfulfilled parts (the part with Nebuchadnezzar destroying Tyre, see below) were not excised from the book. In any case, the other two prophecies were surely not fulfilled until much later after the books of the Tanakh were canonized and reviewed by multitudes of people.

---

The block quotes are cited from http://apologeticspress.org/apcontent.aspx?category=13&article=1790

Regarding the unfulfilled prophecy of Nebuchadnezzar destroying Tyre, see previous link where he tries to resolve the issue, however in my opinion the issue still remains unresolved.

Comment: " But in reality it couldn't have been composed or even edited later than 250 bc " - why not? please explain. thanks

Comment: @ray i wrote in parenthesis - "the date the Septuagint was written". It is obvious that Ezekiel couldn't have been composed later than the translation of the book itself (Septuagint)! Please read link about septuagint https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint

Comment: when was the septuagint written for Ezekiel? any source for that?

Comment: "Modern scholarship holds that the LXX was written during the 3rd through 1st centuries BCE. But nearly all attempts at dating specific books, with the exception of the Pentateuch (early- to mid-3rd century BCE), are tentative and without consensus"

Comment: @ray In Britannica i found https://www.britannica.com/topic/Septuagint. "Analysis of the language has established that the Torah, or Pentateuch (the first five books of the Old Testament), was translated near the middle of the 3rd century BCE and that the rest of the Old Testament was translated in the 2nd century BCE." I modified my post.

Comment: when did "ancient Tyre lay completely buried beneath the sea"? thanks

Comment: @ray 12th century AD as Benjamin of tudela has confirmed.

Comment: you mean it descended into the sea 1400 years later?

Comment: @ray i'm not sure when the southern part (ancient Tzor) actually descended into the ocean, i'm only familiar with the testimony of benjamin in the twelfth century.

Comment: isnt that the main prophecy? ie when it descenced into the ocean